# Taking proportional samples, no bad sampling

Tags: python, algorithm

I want to choose 15 images from many collections. Number of images depends on the proportion of images from that collection.

My code is as:

```
image_counts = [16, 2, 14]
total_images = 0
for i in image_counts:
    total_images += i
proportions = [1.0 * i / total_images for i in image_counts]
counts = [int( round( 15 * i)) for i in proportions]
```

But the output `[8, 1, 7]` adds up to 16, due to rounding. How to get a list that adds up to exactly 15?

Comment: What is better: float(i) or 1.0*i?

Comment: `1.0*i` has a different meaning than `float(i)`. So if you want to convert to float you ought to use `float(i)`.

Comment: @Bakuriu: Well if `i` is integer what is the final difference exactly?

Comment: The result is the same, but while `float(i)` is a conversion operations(and that's quite explicit), the `1.0*i` is a multiplication operation, which _happens_ to convert other kind of numbers to floats. If one day the python developers decided to prohibit implicit conversions then any code using `1.0*i` would break. This probably will never happen, nonetheless you should use the operation that corresponds to what you want to do.
My advice is more than this use-case: using an operation that has a different meaning than what you want to do, but that _happens_ to have the same effects is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your options is this:

```
image_counts = [16, 2, 14]
total_images = sum(image_counts)

proportions = [1.0 * i / total_images for i in image_counts]
counts = [int(15 * i) for i in proportions]
if sum(counts) < 15:
    counts[counts.index(min(counts))] += 1
```

---

To complete this answer:

```
counts[counts.index(min(counts))] += 15 - sum(counts[1:]) # from user1654936
```

and truncating the final list to 15 elements.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases it is not possible to choose the counts exactly according to the calculated proportions. So, because you have to deviate from the proportions anyway, you could just alter e.g. the first number of your `counts` list so that it adds up to the required total number:

```
image_counts = [16, 2, 14]
total_images = sum(image_counts)
proportions = [1.0 * i / total_images for i in image_counts]
counts = [int( round( 15 * i)) for i in proportions]
counts[0] = 15 - sum(counts[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't in general have the total be 15 (or whatever you want) and the correct proportions unless some very specific conditions are satisfied by the number of images in each collection and the number that you want.

So you need to decide how to adjust those numbers to get something close to what you want. Do you want the proportions to be nearly correct (and even now it's only "nearly", since you're already rounding)? Or do you want to allow a number other than 15 in total?

also:

```
total_images = sum(image_counts)
```